# Will a Bowers & Wilkins Zeppelin Air be adequate monitors for sound editing/mixing on a short film?

Tags: monitors, sound-editing, mixing, film

I'm about to embark on a shortish film project, 30mins approx, as the sound editor. I'm responsible for the whole post production phase for this film's sound. It may go for a mastering session at some point in the future. I own a Zeppelin Air that I use daily hooked up to my laptop via USB. If anyone here is familiar with the Zeppelin Airs they're pretty decent, high quality speakers with its own powered amps. Will it be ok as monitors for film sound editing or should I consider investing in dedicated monitors? The only issue I see with them is the limited stereo seperation as it's an all in one system, though I have it set up about 5ft away from me under the screen.

Comment: Yes, I suggest going a different route monitor-wise.  That set looks like a Bose-type unit, and I'd never recommend monitoring any mission-critical work on something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it can work, but likely is highly suboptimal (i.e. what you mix will not necessarily sound very good on normal speakers, only on the Zeppelin or similar units). At the very least for stereo mixing I would suggest a speaker system where you have two separate speakers and you can place them so that they form an equilateral triangle to your listening position. Or headphones.